# Comparing table tr values before and after and get two objects or arrays with difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table structure like this,

```
<table id="dltable" class="dTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="dRow " data-userid="s-1-5-21-34154-1668">
            <td class="dCell" style="width:40px;">
                <img src="1.png" class="avatar" />
            </td>
            <td class="dCell" style="vertical-align: top; padding-top:8px;"><span class="personItem">person 1</span>

            </td>
            <td class="dCell" style="width:30px;">
                <div class="dir-list_tick on hide" onclick="toggleSelection(this);" style="display: block;"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dRow " data-userid="s-1-5-21-3415-3433">
            <td class="dCell" style="width:40px;">
                <img src="2.png" class="avatar" />
            </td>
            <td class="dCell" style="vertical-align: top; padding-top:8px;"><span class="personItem">person 2</span>

            </td>
            <td class="dCell" style="width:30px;">
                <div class="dir-list_tick on hide" onclick="toggleSelection(this);" style="display: block;"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now on edit click button, user may toggleSelection,

```
function toggleSelection(e) {
    var obj = $(e);
    if (obj.hasClass('on')) {
        obj.removeClass("on").addClass("off");
    } else {
        obj.addClass("on").removeClass("off");
    }
}
```

and CSS

```
.dir-list_tick.on {
    background-image: url(/_layouts/15/images/arrow.png);
    background-position: 50%;
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
}

.dir-list_tick.off {
    background-image: url(/_layouts/15/images/arrow_inactive.png);
    background-position: 50%;
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
}
```

Now what I want is that, when user clicks on Edit button, I capture all users with there ids and statuses (atleast for now) e.g.

```
var user = { id: userid, status: 1 if image is arrow or class is on and -1 for not}
```

And then when user clicks on another button Save I want to get all user whoes status (may have more properties in future) has changed from on to off or off to on.

Only way i can think of is to iterate through table again and again to compare them, any easier way of doing it please ?

**Edit**

Based on comments I think i am on right track but i am stuck here,

```
    var beforeEditUsers = [];
    $('#dltable > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
        beforeEditUsers.push({
              id : $(this).attr('data-userid'),
              status :  // how can i cast div with class dir-list_tick on class as one here and otherwise 0 ?
        });
    });
```

**Found it**

```
    var beforeEditUsers = [];
    $('#dltable > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
        beforeEditUsers.push({
              id : $(this).attr('data-userid'),
              status : $(this).children('.dir-list_tick').hasClass('on')
        });
    });
```

Comment: _"Only way i can think of is to iterate through table again and again to compare them"_ <--  You're on the right track there. That's exactly what you need to do.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve, but from the sound of it, you could make it much simpler by assigning a `dirty` flag to rows which have been edited by the user. You can then select these rows when the Save button is clicked and do what you require with them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks maybe you are right, but this way i won't know if user actually changed value or just toggled it, there must be a way around that too but as I may need to add more attributes to this tr so i will follow comparing objects, please see edited question, thanks so much